# Tooltip on 100% width and tip on icon

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am trying to make a tooltip but not working as I want...
Coding is bellow

```
@media only screen and (min-width:500px){
                    #demo{
                        width: 1000px;
                    }
                    .top-icons-path i{
                        font-size: 40px;
                    }
                }

                @media only screen and (max-width:500px){
                    #demo{
                        width: 500px;
                    }
                    .top-icons-path i{
                        font-size: 20px;
                     }
                }


                   #demo {

                    padding: 5px;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    position: relative;
                    border: 4px solid #10859e;
                }
                #demo:after, #demo:before {
                    border: solid transparent;
                    content: ' ';
                    height: 0;
                    bottom: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 0;
                }
                #demo:after {
                    border-width: 9px;
                    border-bottom-color: #fff;
                    left: 5px;
                }
                #demo:before {
                    border-width: 14px;
                    border-bottom-color: #10859e;
                    left: 0px;
                }

                </style>

                    <div class="w3-row-padding website-content">

                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;right:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-right" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" top-icons-path w3-col s1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right w3-tooltip" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span style="position:absolute;right:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-right" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
                            </i>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

I am using w3-css http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css in my file.
I have tried a lot but it's not working properly.
I wanna tip on the icon and wanna top tip on 100% on row. I have tired a lot but not working for me.
Please anyone help me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add following class and css to display tooltip

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right icon-class" aria-hidden="true">
   <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;z-index:50000000000; font-size:18px;" class="w3-text w3-round w3-animate-left" id="demo" style="border:1px solid #10859e;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text </span>
</i>

.icon-class:hover:after {
    content: "Your tooltip";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -16px;
    right: -16px;
    width: 100px;
    background: lightpink;
}
```

It may be help you.

Comment: Hello,<br />Thanks for your reply but it is not like I want. Please check images and let me know if it is possible. https://postimg.org/image/s818nlze3/ this is image one where it is on 1st icon and looking ok but here in css I had to add width 1000px, Check 2nd image https://postimg.org/image/xkq31qnaj/ here when I move it to next icon, it go out of screen. I want that only tip move to icons, not icon box. Hope you got as I want.